# eCos configuration tools for stm32f4vg407

Tags: c++, stm32, stm32f4discovery, ecos

I want to test blink example on stm32f4 discovrey board using eCos RTOS.
But in eCos configtool there is no configuration template for stm32f4.

can anyone help me to turn around this problem ?
thanks

Comment: What prevents you from writing your own template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure to point the configtool to your ecos repository?

[image]

You should see the STM discovery board in the list as shown below.
[image]

If not you might need to check to see if you have an ecos repository with this support.  You can try the ecos repository here:

`hg clone http://hg-pub.ecoscentric.com/ecos/`

Comment: thanks , yes i worked with old version that have'nt stm32 board